# How can I hide the navigation bar with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I am trying to hide the navigation under the footer using Jquery.

I mean, I want to show the navigation until it reaches footer stage. Then, I want to hide it.

How can I do it? or Should I use `z-index` in state of jquery?

**Code and example**: http://jsfiddle.net/yn8r4/1/

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

**NOTE**

I am adding a FIXED position to the navigation with Jquery and I do need the site to looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/yn8r4/1/ and NOT like here: http://jsfiddle.net/yn8r4/14/

**Live Example**

I have found a live example of what I am trying to do [Here](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/)

When you scroll down you would see navigation on the left. Believe, He is using `z-index`. Is he?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by hiding it "under the footer"? If it is hidden, does it matter where it is?

Comment: @Jeremy I have edited it. I hope it makes more sense.

Comment: Is there a reason it is placed fixed? If you just float it next to the content area and cleared it, it would stop before you hit the footer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery for this. In CSS, you could just set the z-index property of #navigation to be smaller than that of #footer.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you're going for: http://jsfiddle.net/AqeXd/1/

```
var top = $('#navigation').offset().top - parseFloat($('#navigation').css('margin-right').replace(/auto/, 0));
var contentBottom = $("#content").height() + top;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (y >= top) {
        $('#navigation').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#navigation').removeClass('fixed');
    }

    var navBottom = top + $("#navigation").height() + y;

    if (navBottom > contentBottom) {
        $("#navigation").hide();
    } else {
        $("#navigation").show();
    }
});​
```

Comment: p.s.  might want to consider assigning `$("#navigation")` to a variable so you don't need to keep selecting it.

Comment: Yes, it is really close to what I am looking for! but I need to hide the navigation bit by bit under the footer. Should I use fadeIn? Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeremy, jQuery is not needed.  It is a simple CSS solution.

You don't need to use z-index at all.  Remove the absolute positioning on the navigation column and float it left next to the content. [Can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/yn8r4/14/)

**CSS**

```
#navigation { float:left;width:140px;height:300px; background-color:#E5450F;}
#navigation p {text-align:center;}

#content {height:300px;width:400px;background-color:#ddd;margin-bottom:10px;float:left;}


#footer {height:300px;width:auto;position:relative;z-index:0;background-color:#5F93AB;margin:;padding:0;text-align:center;}

#footer_b {height:300px;width:300px;background-color:#000;position:relative;z-index:0;color:#fff;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p style="font-size:0.8em;"> * Thanks for your help *</p>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
   <p>Navigation</p>
   <p style="font-size:0.8em;"> * Hide me under footer *</p>
   <p style="font-size:0.8em;margin-top:230px;"> * Hide me *</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
</div>

<div id="footer_b">
    <p>Footer_b</p>
</div>
```